# What would be the equivalent circuit of the following block diagram?

Tags: control, pid-controller, closed-loop

[image]

They gave me the following diagram, in the references they gave me I was able to obtain the PID block circuit, I only need the circuit of the \$\frac{1}{s-2}\$ function, It sounds like an RC circuit to me but I don't know how to get the values of the components.

$$\frac{Y(s)}{U(s)} = \frac{k (s + 1)(s + 2)}{s(s - 2) + k (s + 1)(s + 2)}$$

That is its closed loop transfer function, I don't know if the circuit changes something when taking it in closed loop.

---

I will try to specify myself better:

Basically what was asked of me is to build an electrical circuit where I will build the PID controller and the plant with op-amp / capacitors / resistors), where I will observe through an oscilloscope that the PID controller can stabilize the plant.

I did not know that the plant could do it electrically with op-amp, since in the course we simply saw the response of a passive RC circuit. In any case, what would be the methodology to find the equivalent of my plant in the form of a circuit?

Comment: Miguel Angel Covarrubias - Hi, You wrote an "answer" but it wasn't the answer to your original question. It was additional information, so it has been added to your question as an edit (i.e. an update) instead. || Since you asked the question, unless you are writing the *full and final* answer to your own question (i.e. unless you have solved the problem yourself & don't need further help) please don't use the box labeled "Your Answer" below. Instead, to add more information / clarification, please [edit] the question. || Please see the [tour] and [help] for more rules. Thanks.

Comment: Either you were told and you missed it (and I just violated the spirit of this group's homework policy), or someone is teaching a class without requiring necessary prerequisites.  I've added a circuit example that can, with the right circuit values, realize your unstable pole.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I tried to do some research but I couldn't get the transfer function of the circuit you sent, I have seen examples that use only resistors but when I place the capacitor I don't know how to advance the methodology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the whole point of a block diagram is to present a problem in the abstract, without caring *how* the blocks are realized.  *You should not care* how \$\frac{1}{s - 2}\$ is realized -- just that it exists.

Second, \$\frac{1}{s - 2}\$ is the transfer function of an unstable system -- it has a response with \$e^{2t}\$ in it.  This cannot be realized with a passive network of resistors and capacitors.  You *could* realize it with an op-amp circuit, but unless you are specifically tasked with doing so there's no point.

In general, if you were to see such a block diagram in the field, the \$\frac{1}{s - 2}\$ block would be describing the behavior of the plant, which (A) could be anything at all, electrical, mechanical, thermal, etc., and (B) would already exist, so there's no need to build one.

Here is *a* circuit that will realize a single-order unstable pole.  I'll leave it up to you to find the right circuit constants.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpfmxU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Might be nice to integration-test a realised physical PID?

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, I am new to asking these types of questions and I really think I could learn a lot with answers like yours, I will try to specify myself better. Please see the update to the question. [Edited by a moderator when it was converted into a comment.]